# Flag module not joining flagging with EntityFieldQuery?

Tags: flags, database

I'm using `EntityFieldQuery` to pull nodes based on a flag created with the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module (3.2):

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->range(0, 25)
    ->addTag('flagging_flag_names')
    ->addMetaData('flag_name_value', 'my_flag_name');
```

I'm not seeing the flagging table being joined to the query (from the error being thrown):

```
Unknown column 'flagging.fid' in 'on clause': 
SELECT node.nid AS entity_id, node.vid AS revision_id, node.type AS bundle, 'node' AS entity_type FROM node node INNER JOIN flag f ON flagging.fid = f.fid WHERE (node.status = 1) AND (node.type = 'article') AND (f.name = 'my_flag_name') LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Below is the `flag_query_flagging_flag_names_alter` from the flag module file:

```
function flag_query_flagging_flag_names_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  // Get value and operator for bundle condition from meta data.
  $value = $query->getMetaData('flag_name_value');
  $operator = $query->getMetaData('flag_name_operator');
  // Join [flag] and [flagging] tables by [fid] and
  // apply bundle condition on [flag].[name] field.
  $query->join('flag', 'f', 'flagging.fid = f.fid');
  $query->condition('f.name', $value, $operator);
}
```

What am I missing in the query build to join the flagging table?

Answer (score 4):

The `flagging` table is not available when querying for nodes using an EntityFieldQuery, that's why the `flagging.fid` column is missing in this query.

In order to get hold of flaged items, the flagging-entities need to be queried instead:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'flagging')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'name_of_some_flag');
```

Then use `entity_load('flagging', ...)` and obtain the `nid` from the `entity_id`-property of the flagging entities.

However keep in mind that it is impossible to sort / filter on properties of the target object (nodes in this case) because `EntityFieldQuery` does not support JOINs in Drupal 7.

I suggest to build a view instead of trying to battle the EFQ in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

To get all flagged entities on Drupal 8, plus a condition on the type (here on the type of Node) :

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

$connection = Database::getConnection();

$query = $connection->select('flagging', 'f');
$query->join('node_field_data', 'n', 'n.nid = f.entity_id');
$query->fields('f', ['entity_id', 'entity_type', 'flag_id', 'global'])
  ->fields('n', ['nid', 'type'])
  ->condition('f.flag_id', 'bookmark') // replace by flag machine name
  ->condition('n.type', 'article'); // replace by content type name

$data = $query->execute();
$results = $data->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```